# Is there a way to get all counties in an MSA?

Tags: us-census

Is there a way to get the list of all counties that are part of an MSA/CBSA?

According to this hierarchy, I don't see an obvious way: https://www.census.gov/newsroom/blogs/random-samplings/2014/07/understanding-geographic-relationships-counties-places-tracts-and-more.html

I tried this:

```
https://api.census.gov/data/2015/acs/acs5?get=NAME&for=county:*&in=metropolitan+statistical+area/micropolitan+statistical+area:27260
```

But got this error:

```
error: unknown/unsupported geography heirarchy
```

Is there any other way of getting this info?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Core Based Statistical Areas (CBSAs), Metropolitan Divisions, and Combined Statistical Areas (CSAs) 2018-09](https://www.census.gov/geographies/reference-files/time-series/demo/metro-micro/delineation-files.html) 
[FIPS Metropolitan Area (CBSA) Codes - 2000 Census Documentation](https://www2.census.gov/programs-surveys/cps/methodology/Geographic%20Coding%20-%20Metro%20Areas%20(since%20August%202005).pdf)
**Bonus** [CMS's SSA to FIPS CBSA and MSA County Crosswalk](https://www.nber.org/data/cbsa-msa-fips-ssa-county-crosswalk.html)

Comment: I was looking for an API. In the absence of such an API, I can work with the excel files. Thank you.